# connect-debounce spam on TTY and system suspend

Tags: usb, xubuntu, tty

The below output from *dmesg* shows the same thing I see when I ctrl+alt+F1, if is stop lightdm and sometimes if I suspend the machine.

```
[  615.128020] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  617.048017] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 3 disabled
[  618.968021] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 4 disabled
[  620.888022] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 5 disabled
[  622.808022] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 6 disabled
[  624.728022] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 7 disabled
[  626.648019] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 8 disabled
[  628.568044] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 1 disabled
[  630.488031] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  632.408026] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 3 disabled
[  634.328022] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 4 disabled
[  636.248022] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 5 disabled
[  638.168026] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 6 disabled
[  640.088031] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 7 disabled
[  642.008018] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 8 disabled
[  643.928025] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 1 disabled
[  645.848022] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 2 disabled
[  647.768020] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 3 disabled
[  649.688029] hub 1-0:1.0: connect-debounce failed, port 4 disabled
```

Here is the output from *lsusb*:

```
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 046d:c315 Logitech, Inc. Classic New Touch Keyboard
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 1532:0009 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

When going into TTY I can alt+F7 back into xfce without any issue, but I can't do anything else.

Note:  I KNOW the onboard USB controller is bad. It's REALLY spotty as to whether it will recognize what's plugged in to it. I had to add a PCI controller only a few weeks before rolling over to linux.

Xubuntu 12.10
*uname*
3.5.0-27-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 25 19:58:17 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone still bumping into this it absolutely is the USB controller doing it.  I've had it on Ubuntu and Fedora.

Replaced the USB controller and poof, gone.

Comment: I agree, I have this problem on a 7-years+ old pc, often when I plug in a powered USB hub. I've found that [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/342061/power-on-off-usb-ports/342079#342079) sometimes solves the issue. Anyway, I'm still trying to find a realiable software-only solution :)

Comment: Good luck with that. There may be some module you can unload from the kernel or something, but that's way deeper than my knowledge of linux goes.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and the solution suggested [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=47205) solved my problem.
I simply unplugged my laptop and removed the battery to let the power drain completely and starting my computer again everything worked like a charm. It's worth giving a try before going for more complicated options.

Comment: My onboard USB controller is not bad (as in question) but all USB ports suddenly stopped working on ubuntu 16.04.  This solution fixed the problem.  Note that "Wake on USB" is enabled in the BIOS so the USB ports are never fully off when the battery is there.  As a workaround, a cheap 2 Port USB 3.0 HUB ExpressCard from ebay worked fine until I found this solution.